# How to select specific elements in groups jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 4 fieldsets with form fields inside.

How do I select every first label tag in each fieldset and contain it in a variable?

This is what I tried:

```
var $firstLabel = $('fieldset label');
```

then I called it like:

```
$firstLabel.eq(0)
```

This doesn't exactly work how I need it to work because it only selects the very first label inside the first fieldset, and not each first label in each fieldset.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that `$(fieldset label);` is certanly not correct, it should be `$("fieldset label");`. And you don't have to name your variables with `$` prefix. In JavaScript names like `firstLabel` are often used, `$firstLabel` is rare and unusual (but correct).

Comment: Thanks, yes I actually had it in a string, I just forgot to write it here, sorry about that.

Comment: Just to clarify why I use the unusual dollar sign infront of the variable - I was trained to use it in a variable that returns jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you did the following using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map).

```
var labels = $('fieldset').map(function () {
    return $(this).find('label:first');
});
```

The `labels` variable will be a jQuery set of the 4 labels, so you could iterate over them using [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each);

```
labels.each(function (i) {
    // this function will get called 4 times; each time `this` will be one of the labels.
});
```

Or even assign them to variables;

```
var firstLabel = labels.eq(0);
var secondLabel = labels.eq(1);
```

... etc.

Comment: `$(this).find('label').first();`
OR
`$(this).find('label:first');`

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! Will try these ways, that's pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Arvind07: Yes, the end result is the same. I think `:first` is slightly quicker as it'll probably stop searching for more elements once it's found the first, whereas `.first()` operates *after* all elements have been found.